# php Change color if value negative or positive

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a condition to display negative value in red and positive in green.
This is what I have but I'm unable to get the positive values to be displayed.
What should I do here? How do i use the if / else condition in my situation?

```
<td class="text-center" 
    <?php if($product['quantity'] < 0): ?> { style="color:red; font-weight:bold;" <?php endif; ?>>
    <?php echo $product['quantity'];?> }
</td>
```

Comment: Use CSS classes

Comment: Define some CSS classes and then insert one of them through an `if-else`. You might want to use a ternary to make it simpler.

Comment: What have you done so far to debug this yourself? I'd start by checking your HTML output to see what your code is currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable with the style attributes outside of TD and add in TD-style the variable:

```
<?php
    $styleColor = $product['quantity'] < 0 ? 'color:red' : 'color:green';
?>

<td class="text-center" style="<?php echo $styleColor ?>">
    <?php echo $product['quantity'];?>
</td>
```

OR

Define class in TD-style with ternary operator:

```
<td class="text-center" style="<?php echo($product['quantity'] < 0 ? 'color:red' : 'color:green'); ?>">
    <?php echo $product['quantity'];?>
</td>
```

Comment: You may want to expand on this answer to include their current `class` attribute too. Because if you have `<td class="text-center" class="highlight">output</td>` you're going to have a bad time :).

Comment: Yes, I was adjusting the answer. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use a ternary operator to conditionally set the value of a variable, and always include it as part of your `td`.

```php
<?php

$style = ($product['quantity'] < 0) ? "color:red; font-weight:bold;" : "color:green; font-weight:bold;";

?>

<td class="text-center" style="<?php echo $style ?>" >
    <?php echo $product['quantity'];?>
</td>
```

Comment: I'd recommend moving the quotes to the HTML to keep the PHP slightly cleaner. So `style="<?= $style; ?>"` and `$style = ($q < 0) ? "color: red;" : "";`

Comment: Yes, I agree, this way quotes won't even need to be escaped. Answer edited, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What am I missing here? I"m new to this. I don't get the results in green if bigger than zero. :-(

Comment: Then it might as well be that there is not rule in your stylesheet defaulting the `td` to `color:green`, so I have adjusted the code in the answer to force-set the green color to the TD, try now :)

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping. all good now. great weekend for everyone.

Comment: No problem at all Alex. Glad this works for you. As my answer helped you solving your problem, please consider accepting it, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

To show you an alternative 'technique', you could envisage using [heredoc syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Normally you'd probably want to use a separate CSS file to define styles, but since this is a small example I've added `<span>` text-color styling in the first HEREDOC block.

The [ternary](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) assigns either 'success' or 'failure' to `$style` based on the quantity available.

```
<?php
echo <<<HEREDOC
<style>
 span.success {color: #0F0; }
 span.failure {color: #F00; }
</style>
HEREDOC;

$product['quantity'] = 0;
$style = ($product['quantity'] > 0) ? 'success' : 'failure';

echo <<<HEREDOC
<table><tr>
<td class="text-center" >
    <p>quantity remaining : <span class="$style">{$product['quantity']}<span> </p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
HEREDOC;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel:

```
<span
  @php
     $Color = $yourvalue < 0 ? 'color:red' : 'color:green';
  @endphp

  style="{{$Color}}">  {{$yourvalue}}% 
</span>
```